# Multiple Bounties on Same Question By Same User For Same Amount

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

So earlier, I offered a bounty on a question no-one was paying attention to, and eventually got two almost identical answers at about the same time. I gave the bounty to the user that answered first, but then felt that the other user should have been rewarded too. I checked to see if you could add a bounty for the same amount, but apparently I could only reward a 100 reputation bounty then. Now I feel bad because there's someone who deserved the reward, but there is literally no mathematical way I could reward both users equally.

*Alternatively I could create another account, give myself a bounty with my account, and then reward the other account, but I don't think that's allowed...*

I guess the feature request is that an option to just reward a user reputation, maybe on their profile page.

Comment: So, what's your support-request, which is a feature-request and because it doesn't fit either tag also a discussion?

Comment: Karmic solution: find another outstanding answer from that user and award a +50 bounty to that answer. Karma balanced, mission accomplished.